# How do I do a blockbuster move in Skullgirls?

Tags: skullgirls

I am trying to use Filla's blockbuster move "Gregor Samson". But however hard I try I cannot do the move.

I must be missing something, It really says something about the difficulty of a game when you cant complete the tutorial.

Comment: Stick or keyboard? Mike Z. explained how he "fixed" any exploits related to "keyboard" devices such as the hitbox controller (ie. no sneaky shortcuts) so it should be hard on keyboard; it's hard enough on stick (easier after a while but took me awhile to beat the persky tutorial the first time too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From holding down on the D-PAD (Or joystick), slide it to the back position. Once you're holding back, push any two kick buttons at the same time (X and O on PS3 I think). Make sure you end on the back position. Do it quickly but it doesn't need to be lightning fast.

Try: http://meh.brpxqzme.net/himff/circles.html for more information on inputs

The input you are doing is a quarter circle back

Comment: Thanks, I think my main problem is my timing. How long is my window for combos.

Comment: Very short actually, you need to do each one pretty quickly after another. Some games let you mash the next button, I don't think skull girls does and I remember skull girls being very short in hit stun (The amount of time you have for each attack)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, just do your best at what the guys up there said. Skullgirls is brutal, but we just have to deal with it to beat the game. Also, Peacock sucks to us if you aren't good at this, so if you can't do the special moves just spam a strong regular move you can use.  Like, Cerebellas Titan Punch. (Only character I have beaten the game with so far)